# facebook and google login open in application by sfsafariviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, google-plus

In my app user can login with facebook and google account. but when user click on facebook login or google login he will redirect to safari browser. So apple reject my app with below reason.

We noticed that the user is taken to Safari to sign in or register for an account, which provides a poor user experience. Next Steps To resolve this issue, please revise your app to enable users to sign in or register for an account in the app.

For resolving the issue I added facebook login behavior as the web "FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb". Now when I open it, it is opening in the app only. but when I click on "Not Now" button on here is the facebook screen shot facebook it is crashing my app in the second time. Can anyone have answer to this issue? Also, can any one suggest me how do I solve the google sign on the issue too?

[image]

Comment: can you show the crash report

Comment: it is showing bad acess.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle is cancelled , also i use facebook sdk version 4.17.0

and click not know and works perfectly

```
 facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email", "user_friends"], from:self, handler:
        {
            (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in

            if facebookError != nil
            {
                print("Facebook login failed. Error \(String(describing: facebookError))")
            }
            else if (facebookResult?.isCancelled)!
            {
                print("Facebook login was cancelled.")

            }
            else
            {
                // success
            }

     });
```

see in action

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
yes I have managed it but still crashing in second time. Also for google plus signin do u have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Swift 4.0 snippet:

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email","public_profile"], from: self) { (result, error) in
            if ((error) != nil) {
                // Process error
            } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                // Handle cancellations
            } else {
                // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                // should check if specific permissions missing
                if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil)
                {
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email, name"]) .start(completionHandler: { (connectioon, result, error) in
                        if error == nil
                        {
                            print(result);

                        }
                    })
                }

            }
        }
```

Make sure you have added these below items in info.plist:

```
1.
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbapi</string>
            <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
            <string>fbauth2</string>
            <string>fbshareextension</string>
        </array>

2.  

    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>fbxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>FacebookAppID</key>
        <string>xxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
        <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
        <string>App name</string>
```

Note: iOS should be greater than iOS 9.0 or later to use SFSafariViewController.

Comment: in iOS 11 onwards we dont use SFSafariViewController for attribute tracking

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can u pls let share how can we use it with SFSafariview controller.

Comment: You don't want to call SFSafariViewController, FBSDK will able to handle that, you just need to call above function.

Comment: Make sure you have added right code in appdelegate as per Facebook doc.